# how can i load mapview like android maps app

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview

I'm making some android app with mapview but whenever i try to load mapview, it takes longer time than maps app built in android.

I realized the default maps app loads mapview by stages. It first shows blur images and then details.

How can i implement this feature? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything about this. You are using the available SDK to developers and thats the best you can get.

Note: Google Maps application are not using the SDK we use, they use another way directly from their servers somehow.